# Python3 Print First File Line

Tags: string, python-3.x, awk, text-processing, python-3.3

How can I make Python3 print the first line of a file once I have loaded the file contents? In other words, what is Python3's equivalent to AWK's `awk "NR==1"`?

Comment: its clear that because you know awk you can grok things, but your questions seem to indicate that you haven't read the docs very thoroughly. Python docs are great and if you read through the tutorial you will get answers to questions like this. If you have read the docs and you still need help, you will get fewer down votes if you show us some code and tell us what you have already tried so we can guide you in the right direction. Asking without looking for the answer first is not highly regarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the first line of a file try this:

```
with open('my_file_name') as in_file:
    print(next(in_file))
```

file objects are iterables over lines. so in a for loop like this:

```
with open('my_file_name') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        print line
```

will print all the lines of a file.

Comment: @Devyn to insert code, use backticks around your code. to print one line from the command line like that, try `ls -l | python3 -c "import sys; print(next(sys.stdin))"` ... stdin is just the same as any file-like object.